# Returning REST response to calling function

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, custom-javascript

Is it possible to return the value from a REST response back to the calling function?

In the code below returneddata is always undefined.  In the GetMyData function I can see the REST response and pick off an element...in this case element 1.  But, when I try to return the value for further processing it vanishes.  The var returneddata is undefined.

Is there a way around this? I'm trying to make my REST calls more general.

Thanks.

```
function GetItems()
{
var returneddata=GetMyData();
}
 
GetMyData: function()
    {
         $.ajax({    
            url: oDataUrl,    
            type: "GET",    
            dataType: "json",    
            headers: ="accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",    
            success: function (data) 
            {
                var mydata=data.d.results;
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data.d.results[1]);
                console.log(mydata);
                return mydata;   

                
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log('fail');
            }
        });    
        
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to return the $.ajax() call itself.

```
GetMyData: function(){
   return $.ajax({
        ....
```

That returns a "thenable" value (kinda a promise, but jQuery's version of it).

Comment: Sweet!!!  Thanks.